# Знамя — «Боевое» или «боевое»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика

«...вручено **боевое** знамя такому-то полку».
Как писать? Склоняюсь к тому, что с маленькой (с чего бы писать с большой?). Я права?

Answer (score 2):

*...вручено **Боевое знамя** такому-то полку».*

Боевое знамя – это символ конкретной воинской части, то есть **имя собственное.**

Положение о Боевом знамени воинской части

**Боевое знамя воинской части (далее – Боевое знамя),** вручаемое дивизиям, бригадам, полкам, отдельным батальонам (дивизионам, эскадрильям) и им равным воинским частям, а также военным образовательным учреждениям профессионального образования (далее - воинская часть), является официальным символом и воинской реликвией воинской части, олицетворяет ее честь, доблесть, славу и боевые традиции, указывает на предназначение воинской части и ее принадлежность к Вооруженным Силам Российской Федерации, другим войскам, воинским формированиям и органам.

https://urok.1sept.ru/articles/671620#:~:text=Боевое%20знамя%20воинской%20части%20(далее,к%20Вооруженным%20Силам%20Российской%20Федерации

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Интересный материал о воинских частях (К воинским частям относятся...)

[https://kartaslov.ru/карта-знаний/Воинская+часть](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: странно.... это просто боевое знамя...не Красное знамя....

Comment: Боевое знамя - это термин, а не просто сочетание. Насколько я поняла из статьи, каждая воинская часть имеет собственное Боевое знамя, оформленное особым образом, но по образцу.

Comment: так если их много разных....

Comment: Я думаю, что существует термин "боевое знамя" с нарицательным значением.  Например:  Торжественно были вручены боевые знамена и другим полкам. . Или: История боевых знамен уходит в далекое прошлое. Но  каждому полку вручают собственное (одно) знамя. Например: При вручении воинской части Боевого знамени ей выдается Грамота Президента Российской Федерации к Боевому знамени.  Поэтому надо смотреть ситуацию по тексту.

Answer (score 1):

[боевой](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)
**1.** Относящийся к бою, войне, военным действиям.
**2.** Связанный со службой в армии; свойственный военнослужащим.

I. Если полку вручили знамя, которое побывало на войне, в боях, возможно — старинное (в дар, на хранение), то слово "боевое" пишется со строчной буквы.

В здании школы бойцы нашли пионерское знамя, и оно стало **боевым знаменем** полка. [Л. Школепова. Это было на самом деле // «Наука и религия», 1985]

II. Если же полку вручили знамя, которое будет являться его главным атрибутом, символом, что вероятнее всего, то слово "Боевое" пишется с заглавной буквы.

Наследником славного соединения стал наш полк, к которому перешло **Боевое знамя** дивизии. [А. Н. Орлов. Дневник пехотного лейтенанта: воспоминания об афганской войне (1983)]
Впереди **Боевое знамя**, затем кафедры и преподаватели, за ними ― виновники торжества ― факультеты с выпускными курсами во главе. [В. И. Аблазов. Дневник (1980)]

[Положение Государственного флага Российской Федерации и **Боевого** знамени в строю](https://legalacts.ru/doc/stroevoi-ustav-vooruzhennykh-sil-rossiiskoi-federatsii-utv/)
(Строевой устав Вооруженных Сил Российской Федерации, глава 8)

Comment: Вы считаете, что у конкретного полка есть несколько боевых знамен? Одно с Грамотой Президента, а другие просто знамена и тоже боевые?

Comment: Я так не утверждала. И даже не предполагала.

Comment: Просто не очень понятно, какие знамена воинской части можно писать со строчной буквы (ваш пункт 1).

Comment: Чужие. Старинные. Трофейные, наконец. Для поддержания боевого духа. Мне кажется, что Вы прочитали невнимательно. *...возможно — старинное (в дар, на хранение)...*

Comment: Ну если для поддержания духа, то да.  Но я у Грамоты.ру  кое-что поинтереснее прочитала (о строчных буквах).Вопрос № 294357  
Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно употребляется фраза "боевое знамя воинской части внесли или вынесли на плац или на сцену клуба". Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Оба варианта верны.  Может, "Боевое знамя" только вручают, а потом носят как "боевое знамя".

Comment: @Sharon Грамота часто отвечает только на поставленный вопрос, не замечая других нюансов или даже ошибок.

Comment: И что, это нормально?  Надо бы с этой службой разобраться по-серьезному. А вообще русское письмо не устает удивлять меня своей гибкостью не только в пунктуации, но и в орфографии тоже. Я не исключаю здесь две формы написания в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: Никогда такого не было, и вот опять! :)  Nektoid снова удалился, и у всех сняли баллы. Надо эту ситуацию как-то исправлять, это несправедливо и нелогично.

Comment: @Sharon *Может, "Боевое знамя" только вручают, а потом носят как "боевое знамя".* Не-не! И вручают Боевое, и носят Боевое. У меня в ответе есть достойная ссылка. Например: Рис. 63. Положение Государственного флага Российской Федерации и Боевого знамени для движения торжественным маршем.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Я уже в этом не уверена. Надо реальные тексты смотреть.  Ситуации бывают разные, особо торжественные и не очень.